# where to read cmd input like "myapp.exe input" or "myapp.exe -?" (i using cmd)

Tags: c

When I using Java, i need to type command like`java -?`If user type `-?` at the end, why the application know this to reply output? Please tell me c code to identify the `-?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are passed as the parameters to main():

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("Arg %i is %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
}
```

When compiled and then executed as

```
myProgram.exe arg1 stuff ?
```

It would output

```
Arg 0 is myProgram.exe
Arg 1 is arg1
Arg 2 is stuff
Arg 3 is ?
```

Comment: Also important in your example, `Arg 4 NULL`; Why? `argv` is an *array-of-pointers* where the pointer that follows the last argument is set `NULL`.

Comment: I crawled a bit through the `C` standard and it seems like your definition of main is not standard confomring: "The parameters
argc
and
argv
and the strings pointed to by the
argv
array shall
be modifiable by the program[...]" so `const* argv[]` is appearently not correct according to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

In `C` you have three options for your `main` signature. The first is the one that does not take any parameters `int main(void)`. The second one `int main()` as mentioned in the comments takes any number of parameters but they are unnamed. The third one however has two parameters `int main(int argc, char **argv)` the names of the parameters do not matter they are just commonly used. These two parameters serve the purpose to provide the command line parameters to your program.

- argc: Is the counter variable which holds the number of the provided arguments separated by spaces
- argv: contains the command line arguments as an array of c-strings

Your program implicitely receives always one argument which is the name of the application (or \0 if the host environment can not provide that). Here a little example on how to iterate over the arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically for *conforming* implementations it is `int main (void)`, leaving the parens empty `()` specifies an indeterminate number of arguments. See [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). (note: many embedded systems are intentionally *non-conforming* so they may provide alternative definitions of `main`) But that said, your meaning was clear otherwise.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin right thanks! Thats always a think i forget when using `C`

Answer (score 0):

In C, the main is declared as:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv);
```

the first argument is the number of parameters while the second one is an array of parameters so, for example in your case you would do:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define QUESTION_MARK "-?"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc > 1){
        char *qsmark = argv[1];
        if(strcmp(qsmark, QUESTION_MARK) == 0){
            printf("argv[1] is -?\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Remember that the first argv is the name of the executable.
Please avoid comparing string by hands though, use the standard library to get if what is pointed by qsmark is actually equal to "-?"

Comment: I believe `strcmp()` is the standard library function in `string.h` that you are looking for.

Comment: True, though that was more of a side note, that is why I did not specify it. If it does make the code more clear I will edit it

Comment: You can, it was clear what you were suggesting, but remember, as the teacher, your student will know much less than you and likely coming from Java he has no idea what string comparison functions are available or where they can be found. Always worth dropping at least a sentence to send them off in the right direction with new-found knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `getopt()` or other similar POSIX functions. Then this is one way to go:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "h?")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case '?':
        case 'h':
            printf("Usage: bla bla\n");
            break;    
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Example:

```
~ # /tmp/temp_test -?
Usage: bla bla

~ # /tmp/temp_test -y
/tmp/temp_test: invalid option -- 'y'
Usage: bla bla
~ #
```

More information in [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long).